# Replacing color with a texture in asp.net core c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics, asp.net-core, imagesharp

I've been experimenting on an image processor called ImageSharp since System.Drawing is not available on asp.net core, and System.Drawing can have its woes.

I want to fill whitespace, with a specific texture from an image. The code below is working, but painfully slow.

Because this is my first time processing images, I don't really know what the most efficient way of doing this.

What's the best and efficient way of filling white space with a texture.

Resulting this:
[Doughnut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPUVf.png)

To This:
[Sparkly Doughnut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwAdq.png)

```
    public void CreateImage()
    {
        var webRoot = _env.WebRootPath;
        var ImgSrc = "\\Images\\SampleImage.png";
        var TextureURL = "\\Images\\Starsinthesky.jpg";
        var file = webRoot + ImgSrc;
        var texture = webRoot + TextureURL;
        var myPath = Path.Combine(webRoot, ImgSrc);

        byte[] img;

        using (Image<Rgba32> image = Image.Load(file))
        {
            HashSet<Texture> textureArr = getRGBaBytes(texture, image);
            for (int h = 0; h <= image.Height; h++)
            {
                for(int w = 0; w <= image.Width; w++)
                {
                    if(image[w,h] == Rgba32.FromHex("#ffffff"))
                    {
                        image[w, h] = textureArr.Where(t => t.x == w && t.y == h).First().color;
                    }
                }
            }
            image.Save("NewImage.png");
        }
    }

    public HashSet<Texture> getRGBaBytes(string textureURL, Image<Rgba32> sample)
    {

        using (Image<Rgba32> tex = Image.Load(textureURL))
        {
            int bitsizelimit = int.MaxValue;    
            if (sample.Width > tex.Width || sample.Height > tex.Height)
            {
                throw new Exception("Texture image dimensions must be greater or equal to sample image");
            }

            HashSet<Texture> myTexture = new HashSet<Texture>();
            for (int h = 0; h <= sample.Height; h++)
            {
                for (int w = 0; w <= sample.Width; w++)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{tex[w,h].ToHex()} at x:{w} y:{h}");
                    myTexture.Add(new Texture { color = tex[w, h], x = w, y = h });
                }
            }
            return myTexture;
        }
    }

    public class Texture
    {
        public Rgba32 color { get; set; }
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of using the `HashSet` when you are creating the `Texture` collection, why not just use a two dimensional array, you are basically using as such already. That should help your performance. I was going to make a test program and test this out, but I can't get this to run in LinqPad, sorry.

Comment: Another thing that may help is to promote this line `Rgba32.FromHex("#ffffff")` to outside your doubly nested loop. The optimizer may notice that it is a constant and would only perform the creation once, but if it doesn't, then you are creating the same color for every pixel in the image, just so you can check if it is white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knocked up a little console app to demonstrate how simple it is to achieve what you want but first I'll explain why your approach is slow.

1. `getRGBaBytes` is not required. You're essentially looping through both images and creating a class for each pixel in your textured image. That's a lot of memory allocations!
2. You have a Linq query within each pixel operation. `Where` and `First`. Again, massive memory allocation for each pixel in the image. There's no need for this.
3. You're doing a comparison against a new `Rgba32` struct each time parsing from a hexadecimal value which will be slow. This can be done using the static `Rgba32.White` struct instead.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("output");
    using (var img = Image.Load("LPUVf.png"))
    using (var texture = Image.Load("stars.jpg"))
    {
        if (img.Width >  texture.Width || img.Height > texture.Height)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Image dimensions must be less than or equal to texture dimensions!");
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
            {
                var pixel = img[x, y];
                if (pixel == Rgba32.White)
                {
                    img[x, y] = texture[x, y];
                }
            }
        }

        img.Save("output/LBUVf.png");
    }
}
```

Here's the output from my sample. (I think I may have actually used the same starscape image :)) You can improve on and reduce any leftover white areas by testing whether each `Rgba32` component is within a range of `255` but I'll leave that to you.

[image: Sample output]

P.S The ImageSharp.Drawing package contains methods that can allow drawing of textures to polygons. Theoretically you could create the new image from scratch if you knew the dimensions of each composite part.

Update:

I couldn't help myself so I wrote some code to reduce leftover pixels.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("output");
    const int min = 128; // Grey midpoint
    using (var img = Image.Load("LPUVf.png"))
    using (var texture = Image.Load("stars.jpg"))
    {
        if (img.Width >  texture.Width || img.Height > texture.Height)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Image dimensions must be less than or equal to texture dimensions!");
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
            {
                var pixel = img[x, y];
                if (pixel.R >= min && pixel.G >= min && pixel.B >= min && pixel.A >= min)
                {
                    img[x, y] = texture[x, y];
                }
            }
        }

        img.Save("output/LBUVf.png");
    }
}
```

As you can see that is much nicer.

[image: Updated sample with better result]

Comment: Tried and tested. Miles better :D

And a huge thank you for your time to add code to remove the jagged edges

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)